# ssh-keygen: illegal option -- m

Tags: openssl, redhat

I'm following this:

https://www.bjornjohansen.no/encrypt-file-using-ssh-key

but this line:

```
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -oaep -pubin -inkey <(ssh-keygen -e -f recipients-key.pub -m PKCS8) -in secret.key -out secret.key.enc
```

is failing here `-m PKCS8` giving `ssh-keygen: illegal option -- m`.

I'm on RedHat Linux 6.5. What's the purpose of this flag and what are the alternatives on RH6.5?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the purpose of this flag

There are multiple formats to encode an RSA public key.

The three most common are:

- the one-line format used in your recipients-key.pub file;
- the RFC 4716 SSH Public Key File Format, that is nearly the same as the one in your recipients-key.pub, but there is a header, a footer and multiple lines are used. The key parameters are **not** encoded with ASN.1;
- the PKCS#8 format, that has a header, a footer, **and that is using ASN.1 to encode the parameters**.

Before OpenSSH v5.6, ssh-keygen was only able to convert from the first to the second one. So, no parameter was needed.

Beginning with OpenSSH v5.6, ssh-keygen can convert from the first to the second format, or from the first to the third one. **So, there are two possibilities. This is why you have this new parameter**.

> what are the alternatives on RH6.5?

Use this Python script and some basic tools to convert to the PKCS#8 format needed by openssl:

```
# yum install python-pyasn1
# curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thwarted/1024558/raw/19fd80a5caf648eeba3b003e8f0fd90c6614fef5/sshpub-to-rsa > convert.py
# openssl rsautl -encrypt -oaep -pubin -inkey <(python convert.py <(awk '{ print $1" "$2" "$3; }' < recipients-key.pub) | sed 2,3d) -in secret.key -out secret.key.enc
```